# Import from Excel then INSERT and UPDATE accordingly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am provided new data in excel table (couple hundred rows). I need to insert new rows or update existing if they are already in target table. Target table in database have more columns than Excel file.

I am trying to automate the process, but also want to follow good practices (which I'm not familiar with as I'm new to SQL in general). Also my target is to do as much as possible with SQL Server (no SSIS available) and as little with Excel.

Excel input:

```
Row1Val1  Row1Val2  
Row2Val1  Row2Val2  
Row3Val1  Row3Val2  
Row4Val1  Row4Val2  
Row5Val1  Row5Val2
```

I use =CONCATENATE within Excel to prepare VALUES for variable table (described later). It's 'manual' step but provided file may need some adjusting anyway, so copying formula from KB article (that I want to create) doesn't add much work.

```
=CONCATENATE("('";A1;"','";B1;"'),")
```

I decided against OPENROWSET because I read somewhere that for excel files it's not supported(?) and may crash database.

Next I load values into variable table and user cursor to INSERT or UPDATE every row. Here's code:

```
DECLARE @NEW_VALUES TABLE(
 VAL1 nvarchar(18) not null,
 VAL3 nvarchar(max) not null
 )
DECLARE @new_value1(18),
 @new_value2 nvarchar(50),
 @new_value3 nvarchar(max),
 @new_value4 nchar(1)

--Default values:
SET @new_value2 = NULL 
SET @new_value4 = 0

INSERT INTO @NEW_VALUES 
VALUES -- Copy values from excel file, remove comma from last line!

DECLARE new_values CURSOR
 FOR SELECT VAL1, VAL3 FROM @NEW_VALUES
 OPEN new_values
 FETCH NEXT FROM new_values INTO @new_value1, @new_value3
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
 BEGIN 
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_WITH_VALUES WHERE VAL1 = @new_value1)
   UPDATE TABLE_WITH_VALUES
    SET VAL1 = @value1,
     VAL2 = @value2,
     VAL3 = @value3,
     VAL4 = @value4
    WHERE VAL1 = @new_value1
   ELSE
    INSERT INTO TABLE_WITH_VALUES
     (VAL1,
     VAL2,
     VAL3,
     VAL4)
    VALUES
     (@new_value1
     ,@new_value2
     ,@new_value3
     ,@new_value4)
  FETCH NEXT FROM new_values INTO @new_value1, @new_value3
 END
 CLOSE new_values;
DEALLOCATE new_values;
```

It works fine but (I mentioned before) I'm new to SQL and I don't know best practices. I am looking for any comments that would help me do this better. I suspect this solution is acceptable for <1000 rows, but I may need different approach in future with more rows.

Also it may be needed to import 3 columns instead of two. IMO this code looks easy enough to alter but any comments are appreciated. This task will have to be performed monthly, so I want to automate it mainly for practice.

Comment: SSIS is your friend, what do you mean by its not available ? Also if you are new to SQL Server, listen to other people what they has to say about your possible options and not rule out your options because you have read something on the internet somewhere.

Comment: It's not installed/setup or there is some other reason. I did find some great looking tutorial for this using SSIS but when I asked my team, they knew nothing about it. So I just searched for another (acceptable) solution.

Comment: Is there some reason you need a cursor there.  Why can't you just do an update WHERE val1 NOT IN (SELECT val1 FROM @newvalues)

Comment: Excluding SSIS as an option, you could try using the built in Import Wizard feature. You'd go about doing this by: opening SSMS, connect to your server, expand databases, right click the database that will hold your imported data, expand tasks and click import data. From there you just follow along. I don't know if you could automate this but it may be possible through the use of a sql server agent job. Hope this info is useful!